# Can we make orbit abbreviations synonyms for the orbits?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

https://space.stackexchange.com/tags/geosynchronous/synonyms does not have any synonyms.  If we look at [What is the maximum mass of a satellite that can be placed in GEO?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1359/what-is-the-maximum-mass-of-a-satellite-that-can-be-placed-in-geo) we see a question riddled with GEO (geostationary orbit) tagged with *geosynchronous* which is usually abbreviated GSO.  If  GEO = GSO is a whole different conversation but at the very least we should have the abbreviation for each orbit as synonyms for them.

Comment: Geostationary orbit (GEO) is a type of Geosynchronous orbit (GSO), but the question probably should be tagged with the more specific tag.

Comment: @called2voyage - Done

Answer (score 3):

Agreed, and I went ahead and done it already, since it's easy enough to reverse it, or apply changes, if we deem it necessary at a later date. I also took the liberty of adding synonyms with a postfix *"-orbit"* to both, so they appear in the list of suggested tags whenever someone enters *"orbit"* in the input field. So, at the moment, we have:

- [geosynchronous](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geosynchronous)   ←   [gso](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gso), [geosynchronous-orbit](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geosynchronous-orbit)
- [geostationary](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geostationary)       ←   [geo](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geo), [geostationary-orbit](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geostationary-orbit)
- [sun-synchronous](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sun-synchronous)  ←   [sso](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sso), [sun-synchronous-orbit](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sun-synchronous-orbit)
- [low-earth-orbit](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/low-earth-orbit)      ←   [leo](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leo)

Feel free to dispute my decision though. Either in the comments, by votes, and/or by adding your own view to it as another answer. Also, please don't hesitate to suggest an edit for the question you mention, to make them more precise with their wording, to delete or include any of the tags in them, or otherwise improve them. Do take care not to create too many revisions on the posts tho, so please edit to correct or improve as many things as possible in a single revision. Cheers!

Comment: What about for LEO? [tag:low-earth-orbit] doesn't currently have [tag:leo] as a synonym

Comment: @called2voyage - Good call. And done! ;)